# Doctrine ODM + MongoDB not empty embedded document persisted as empty

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm fighting this for several hours now and I give up. Maybe someone will help.

I have these documents:

```
/** ODM\MappedSuperclass */
class Document {

    public function &__get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}

/** @ODM\Document */
class User extends Document {
    ...

    /** @ODM\EmbedOne(targetDocument="ProfilePhotoContainer") */
    protected $profilePhoto;

    ...
}

/** @ODM\EmbeddedDocument */
class ProfilePhotoContainer extends Document {

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="ProfilePhoto", simple="true") */
    protected $main;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="ProfilePhoto", simple="true") */
    protected $big;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="ProfilePhoto", simple="true") */
    protected $medium;

    /** @ODM\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="ProfilePhoto", simple="true") */
    protected $small;
}

/** @ODM\Document */
class ProfilePhoto extends Document {

    /** @ODM\File */
    protected $image;

    /** @ODM\Int */
    protected $size;
}
```

I insert the profile photo in several size versions. Works. Then I want to create new user and set the profilePhoto embedded document properties to each of the objects representing each image size version. I set it and persist the user. Then when I look into the database, I see this:

```
db.User.find().pretty()
{
    "_id": ObjectId("SOME_ID"),
    "profilePhoto": {

    },

    # and other unimportant values
}
```

The references to the images aren't persisted in the embedded document `profilePhoto`. I don't get it.

In other words - I first persist some images. Than I create new user and set it's profile photo to reference those images. Then I persist the user but the references to the images are lost...